# Pronoun Dilemma - "The winners of the contest were Morgan and me / Morgan and I

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

In the sentence *'The winners of the contest were Morgan and I',* is 'I' or 'me' correct? I think it should be 'I', because *'Morgan and I were the winners of the contest.'*

Comment: Use the same word you would use for "It was I" or "It was me".  Aren't there already questions here about that?

Comment: I've run out of closevotes today, but you appear to have asked effectively the same question in [Proper pronoun choice underneath a photo … 'The kids and I' or 'The kids and me'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154874/). (You're a significant cause of the fact that I run out of closevotes! :)

Comment: Why say it that way? _Morgan and I were the winners of the contest_, or _won the contest_, does the job without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

"Me".

"The winner of the contest was me." → "The winners of the contest were Morgan and me."

"I was the winner of the contest." → "Morgan and I were the winners of the contest."

You could of course say, "The winner of the contest was I." It's grammatically correct. (A subject complement.) But personally I find it sounds a little dated. And transferred to two winners ("Morgan and I") even more so.

Comment: Further, the practice of using nominative pronouns for subject complements is arguably all part of a conspiracy started by Latin schoolmasters.

Comment: ... Isn't most of English? BBC is hyper-correcting to things like 'It's goodnight from Julie and I'. And some 'authorities' are saying this is acceptable. The 'I find ...' argument is hardly objective. I personally find "The winner of the contest was I" sounds worse than "The winners of the contest were Morgan and I." But I would, like you, use 'me' here.