# Etymology of "let us" and "let's"

Tags: etymology, apostrophe, contractions, imperatives

The verb ***let*** means  “allow”, “permit”, “not prevent or forbid”, “pass, go or come”  and it's used with an object and the bare infinitive.

> 1. Are you going to **let me** drive or not?
> 2. Don't **let him** off the hook.
> 3. Before we **let our children** surf the Internet, they have to do their homework.
> 4. She **lets the cats** out before leaving.
> 5. He **let us** into the house.

The full form *let us* can be used similarly

> 6. **Let us** know as soon as possible.
> 7. Please, **let us** help you.
> 8. They will never **let us** forget.

None of the above can be contracted; however, when **let us** is used for making a suggestion; giving self-encouragement; expressing a consequence or plea,  it is often contracted to **let's**

> **Let's** go out
>   **Let's** have a party
>   **Let's** see what happens
>   **Let's** stand together in this emergency
>   **Let's** not forget those who sacrificed their lives

---

Questions

- I believe that **let + us** is the only instance where this type of contraction occurs. Is there an explanation as to why verbs such as (i) **give + us**, (ii) **get + us** or (iii) **take + us** were not similarly contracted?
- When was the apostrophe used to replace the omitted letter "u" in **let us**?
- What is the origin of **let's**?

Comment: _Give us_ can be contracted (though it usually means _give me_ [no, _gimme_] when it is), often spelt in various more or less nonce ways: _giss a kiss_ is common, for instance.

Comment: I suspect the contraction arose simply because that particular use is so common (like all the _n't_ contractions for negatives) and has a phrasal meaning. In all the other uses, _us_ serves an important semantic role, so it's harder to contract away.

Comment: In contrast, there aren't many idiomatic, phrasal uses of _take us_ or _give us_, except perhaps the example @JanusBahsJacquet gave.

Comment: "Let them" is spoken, and can be written as "let 'em", as can "let 'er", etc. I've never, in fact, seen "Let her rip!" (Not saying it hasn't been written; [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=let+%27er+rip%2C+let+her+rip&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clet%20%27%20er%20rip%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clet%20her%20rip%3B%2Cc0) shows that that was the predominant way to write it before 1960.)

Comment: @Josh61 - Let us go then, **you and I**,/When the evening is spread out against the sky/Like a patient etherised upon a table;/Let us go, through certain half-deserted streets,/The muttering retreats/Of restless nights in one-night cheap hotels/And sawdust restaurants with oyster-shells:/Streets that follow like a tedious argument/Of insidious intent/To lead you to an overwhelming question… /Oh, do not ask, “What is it?”/Let us go and make our visit. (That was T.S. Elliot, by the way, not a personal invite. Didn't want to change the quotation marks.)

Comment: As to your first question, _A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language_ calls _let's_ a "_quasi-modal_". As such it is followed by a second verb "_let's go .., let's eat ..., let's not be late_". etc. in a way that regular transitive verbs _give_, _get_ and _take_ are not. The _let-imperative_ is an interesting, complex topic; _The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language_ devotes more than 5 pages to it.

Comment: @Shoe fancy providing a gist of those five pages? :)

Comment: @Mary-Lou. I could do, but the information there answers none of your three questions!

Comment: @Shoe bugger! :(  I could ask about its peculiar usage,  but then people would repeat  it is the contracted form of *let us*, and that it is used commands, making suggestions etc. How could I phrase it? 1) How is  *let's* dissimilar to *(we) shall* ? If we can make suggestions using "Shall we?" why was *let's* adopted? I would receive answers on the line of: *Let's* is more forceful and encouraging, it is less tentative and timid than *"Shall we?"* Nevertheless, the subject of "usage" is connected to its etymology, isn't it?

Comment: I think you would have to ask a new question - removing the stuff about etymology, which is not covered in the CGEL. This extract (p934) might provide a pointer: "In 1st person inclusives _us_ can be contracted to _'s_, whereas in ordinary imperatives, it can't: _Don't make us/*'s look ridiculous; he won't let us/*'s join._ As it stands, _Let us go with her_ is ambiguous between a 1st person inclusive (_I propose that we go with her_) and an ordinary imperative (_Allow us to go with her_), but if we reduce the _us_ to _'s_, only the first possibility remains."

Comment: But that is why I included the examples 5 (although past tense), 6,7, and 8. I can see that *let's* does not work in those instances, it all boils down to meaning. Anyway, thanks for the excerpt.

Comment: Interesting question! Your last example for “Let’s” (in the negative), could even give rise to an interesting discussion of how “let’s” should/can be negated.  I generally prefer the “let’s not” form as in your example (probably most often in “Let’s not & say we did.”  But I have heard/said “Don’t let’s” & even the questionable “Let’s don’t” to negate “Let’s.” (Aside: the negative form of ‘let’s” often captures the inherently negative notion of ‘lest,” so is it possible that “let’s” in its negative form came from 'misuse' of the similarly spelled “lest” [“let’s not forget”/”lest we forget”]?)

Comment: _Let's_ (frozen when contracted) is another of those modal hangers-on like _hafta, gotta, oughta, need,_ etc. that have modal properties (like negating on either side, e.g _don't need to `V` ~ need not `V`_) is, as you say, a suggestion. It can be used to make a request, or an invitation, or a command, depending on the situation and the relative status of speaker and addressee. Like all modals and modalesques, it's followed by an infinitive. The original form was probably a stylized command, or a magical use of _may_: _(May you) let us `V` (together)_.

Comment: @JohnLawler why is the expression "let us consider" not contracted, (according to Ngram) isn't it first person plural *and* inclusive? I found that result surprising, along with "let's away", an expression I don't think I've ever heard before.

Comment: "Let's away" is 18th and 19th century romantic idiom. Gone now. And "Let us consider" is contracted as often as not in my experience. In math classes, pretty much all the time.

Answer (score 7):

It appears that the  contracted form of ‘let us’, *let's* has acquired idiomatic meaning and usage through the years.

*Let's go* and *let us go*, may convey different meanings. *Let us go* in the sense of *allow us to go*, may not be replaced with *let's*.

Let's see why:

[Usage note](http://www.yourdictionary.com/let-s):

> - *Let’s* is always inclusive, which refers to both the speaker and the addressee, while *let us* is commonly exclusive, which refers only to the speaker. (www.yourdictionary.com)
>
>   - *Let's go, we are late. - inclusive we*
>   - *Release us and let us go! - exclusive we*

According to the following [source](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2012/03/let-us.html):

> - *Merriam-Webster’s Dictionary of English Usage*  -  describes the construction as idiomatic and has this to say: “*Let’s* can also be followed by a pair of pronouns in either the nominative or the objective case; the constructions occur in both American and British English.”
>     and it notes that these  *“are idiomatic constructions—no matter what the case of the pronoun—found almost exclusively in spoken English.”*
>
>   - **Some grammarians believe that “let’s” is treated here as a single unit rather than a contraction of “let us”—that is to say, the “us” is swallowed up.** Consequently, the speaker senses that “let’s” needs some propping up, and adds “you and me” or the slightly more formal-sounding “you and I.”
>   - A modern grammarian might say that “us” or ’s has been **“desemanticized”** or has experienced “semantic loss,” and thus requires additional information in the way of “lexical support.”
>   - It’s been argued now and then that because the object pronoun “us” is part of the contraction, any propping up should be done with pronouns in a similar case. By this argument, “let’s you and me” is preferable to “let’s you and I.”
>   - But in our opinion, that argument merely creates the illusion that “correctness” is possible (or even desirable) here. *As the OED says, this is an “irregular phrase” no matter what the case.*

(www.grammarphobia.com)

Etymology:

> - [Merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/let%27s) says that the first known use of *let's*, a contraction of *let us*, dates back to 1567.
> - The contraction “let’s” has been around since at least as far back as Elizabethan times. Shakespeare used it hundreds of times in his plays, including King Henry VI, Part II,  with its famous line:
> - *“The first thing we do, let’s kill all the lawyers.”*

- As to why the contraction is used with  *let* and not with *give or take* for instance, I think that *let's* (as encouragement or as exhortation) is such a specific, often used, and natural expression whose common use has probably contributed to its diffusion.

Comment: That usage note is very interesting (where is it from, though?). I never realised before that _let’s_ is actually, contrary to more or less everything else in the English language, strictly inclusive. English doesn’t have specific inclusive/exclusive pronouns, but it seems it does have a strictly inclusive verb–pronoun sememe!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Is is from Wiktionary, not my favorite source, but I think the note is   helpful.

Comment: @Janus. Quirk et al. in _A comprehensive Grammar of the English Language_ (p830) note: "In very colloquial English _let's_ is sometimes used for a first person singular imperative as well: _Let's give you a hand_." Another example is: _Let's have a look_, which "can refer to the speaker alone."

Comment: @Shoe True; but I rather feel that’s a slightly different thing. Especially the first one: it still requires a _you_ to be present and, to me at least, somehow semantically involved in the imperative. The second one, I’d say, is just a dialectal feature, using plural _us_ for singular _me_ in general (“Give us a a kiss” and “Let’s hear it” are often singular, and dialectally, so can “He gave us a tenner” be).

Comment: @Janus. Agreed; I thought it helpful to point out that _let's_ is not always a _1st person inclusive_.

Answer (score 5):

### Why the apostrophe?

The brainchild of a Frenchman called  Geoffroy Tory, the apostrophe was born in 1529 and adopted by British typographers in 1559. Originally, its use was to show a missing vowel letter, and it was used mainly to show spoken English, as in a play script. In the case of ‘let's’, the apostrophe substituted the letter -u. Thus  an English word such as *loved*, could be written as *lov'd*, the article *the* could be represented as *th'*, and *agree* could be spelled *'gree*. This also explains why ‘it is’ and ‘it was’  were often contracted to ‘tis and ‘twas.

> Initially, the apostrophe was intended to demonstrate the elision of a
>   vowel, meaning the vowel sound had been omitted, assimilated, or
>   slurred in pronunciation, as in *th’ inevitable end*, but the apostrophe
>   was also used to indicate a missing letter when the vowel no longer
>   existed in the spoken form, as in *can’t* (Parkes, 1993, p.55).
>
> <sub><sup>Parkes, M.B. *Pause and Effect: An Introduction to the History of Punctuation in the West*</sup></sub>

### Early examples of the apostrophized ‘let's’

*The Proverbs, Epigrams, and Miscellanies* of John Heywood (**1562**)
(edition printed 1906)

> Thy tales, (quoth he), *show long hair, and short wit, wife:
>
>   But long be thy legs, and short be thy life.*
>   *Pray for yourself!* I am not sick, (quoth she).
>   Well [let's see](https://books.google.it/books?id=pK07AAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=snippet&q=let's%20see&f=false), what they last tale cometh to, (quoth he):
>   Thou sayest I spend all; to this, thy words wander;
>   *But, as deep drinketh the goose as the gander.
>
>   Thou canst cough in the aumbry*, if need be,  [. . .]

*The Shepheards Garland, Fashioned in Nine Eglogs* (**1593**)
By Michael Drayton, John Payne Collie

> Come frolick it a while my lustie swayne,
>   [Let's see](https://books.google.it/books?id=kJ5TAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA28&dq=%22let%27s%20see%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AcYgVdWkJo2PaPD3gKAM&ved=0CDcQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22let's%20see%22&f=false) if time haue yet reui'd in thee,
>   Or if there be reayning but a grayne,
>   Of the olde stocke of famous poesie,
>   Or but one slip yet left of this same sacred tree.

*Have with You to Saffron-Walden Or, Gabriell Harveys Hunt is Up*
By Thomas Nashe, ‎John Payne Collier (**1596**) [p.43 [let’s have](https://books.google.it/books?id=aZ5TAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA43&dq=%22let%27s%20have%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=E94nVcTaAs-WasSHgegC&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22let's%20have%22&f=false)]

[image]

*The Taming of the Shrew*  By William Shakespeare  (**1596**)
(edition printed in 1885)

> But come, [let's go unto Alfonso's house](https://books.google.it/books?id=sQkWAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA4&dq=%22let%27s%20go%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pMYgVe6dLIP2arKlgtAI&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22let's%20go%22&f=false),
>   And see how Valeria and Kate agrees;
>   I doubt his music scarce will please his scholar.
>   But stay, here comes Alfonso.

*Laura: The Toys of a Traveller or The Feast of Fancy* (**1597**)
By Robert Tofte

> Th’ immortal PARCÆ, fatal Sisters three,
>   Of mortal men, do sing the shunless fate:
>   What once Was, what Is now, and what Shall Be;
>   Their life, their death, their fortune, and their state.
>   Our Song let be like theirs! for Three they were;
>   And so our number is. Three are we here.
>   Sing Laura then! Sing Love! and sing will I!
>   Of dreary fortune mine, sing let us all!
>   [Let's sing in doleful tune](https://books.google.it/books?id=3MY3AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA400&dq=let%20s%20have&hl=en&sa=X&ei=I94nVaiVJ5WxaZy9gJAB&ved=0CFQQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=let%20s%20have&f=false) most mournfully.
>   How 'Tis, how Twas, and hapless still Shall fall ;
>   The Present, Past, and (which none can mend) 
>   What Shall Be, world to come, withouten end.

By the same author. Three examples of ***let's*** in one sonnet.

[image]

*Skialetheia. or, A Shadowe of Truth, in certaine Epigrams and Satyres* (**1598**)
This edition printed in 1843

> Oh what a slauerie's this? Shall a free mind
>   Sicke of a Cockneys ague, feare the wind?
>   No, [let's be Stoicks](https://books.google.it/books?id=PjYJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PT67&dq=%22let%27s%20be%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0cYgVZyuFtfUaojTgKAK&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22let's%20be%22&f=false), resolute, and spare not
>   To tell the proudest criticke that we care not
>   For his wooden censure, nor to mittigate
>   The sharp tart veruice of his snap-haunce hate

Law-trickes <sub><sup>OR,</sup></sub> *Who Would Have Thought It*.
Written by John Day (**1608**)

> *Can*. Impute the gross mistake to the fault of the Author:—You shall likewise see the amorous Conceits and Love songs betwixt Captain *Pod of Pycorner* and Mrs. *Rump* of *Ram-alley*, never described before.
>
> *Swash*. Good master, [let's see](https://books.google.it/books?id=QaUsAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA2-PA73&dq=%22let%27s%20see%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XsUgVa_0F5D7asO0gMgB&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22let's%20see%22&f=false) Mrs. *Rumps* of *Ramm-alley*.
>   *Y. Str*. How? Captain *Pod* and Mrs. *Rump*? I think this snuffling slave flouts us: then y'faith **let's see** the sawing of the Devil with a wooden saw.

### [let us away](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=let%20us%20away%2Clet%27s%20away&year_start=1560&year_end=1750&corpus=18&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clet%20us%20away%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clet%20%27s%20away%3B%2Cc0) vs. [let’s away](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=let%20us%20away%2Clet%27s%20away&year_start=1750&year_end=1950&corpus=18&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clet%20us%20away%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clet%20%27s%20away%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Clet%20us%20away%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Clet%20's%20away%3B%2Cc1)

The following is an excerpt from a [wiktionary discussion](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk:away) [emphasis mine]

> I don’t see *away* as a verb at all. It’s an adverb. *Let's away* is not an unusual or antiquated use of *[away](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/away)*, but of **let’s**. In Modern English, *let's* requires a verb, as in *let's go (away)*.  [. . .] it just means “let's go”, “let's leave”, “let's depart”. [. . .] *let's* is very similar to the modal verbs *can*, *could*, *may*, *might*, *must*, *shall*, *should*, *will*, *would*, *ought*, *need* and *dare*, in that in Modern English it needs to govern an infinitive verb (*let's do it*, *let's eat*), but in earlier times the infinitive could be elided and implied, as in “let's away”.

Google Ngram 1560 to 1750 
[image]

Google Ngram  1750 to 1950 
[image]

### [let us/let’s away](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=let%20us%20away%2Clet%27s%20away%2Clet%20us%20go%2Clet%27s%20go&year_start=1570&year_end=1750&corpus=18&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clet%20us%20away%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clet%20%27s%20away%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clet%20us%20go%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clet%20%27s%20go%3B%2Cc0) vs. [let us/let’s go](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=let%20us%20away%2Clet%27s%20away%2Clet%20us%20go%2Clet%27s%20go&year_start=1750&year_end=1990&corpus=18&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clet%20us%20away%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clet%20%27s%20away%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clet%20us%20go%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clet%20%27s%20go%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Clet%20us%20away%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Clet%20's%20away%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Clet%20us%20go%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Clet%20's%20go%3B%2Cc1)

[image]
[image]

### [Let us see](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=let%20us%20see%2Clet%27s%20see&year_start=1560&year_end=1750&corpus=18&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clet%20us%20see%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clet%20%27s%20see%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Clet%20us%20see%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Clet%20's%20see%3B%2Cc1) vs. [let’s see](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=let%20us%20see%2Clet%27s%20see&year_start=1750&year_end=1990&corpus=18&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clet%20us%20see%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clet%20%27s%20see%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Clet%20us%20see%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Clet%20's%20see%3B%2Cc1)

*Let's see* is an idiomatic expression, used when the speaker is thinking or trying to remember something, *let us see* was first recorded in 1520.

[image]
[image]

### ‘let us consider’ vs. ‘let's consider’

This Ngram chart is probably indicative as to when and why “let us” is contracted to *let's*. The formal-sounding expression “[let us consider](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22let%20us%20consider%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1963,cd_max:2006&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=8iouVZyEPYbmywPu9ICgCA#q=%22let%20us%20consider%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1963,cd_max:2006,lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&start=0)” is more likely to be found in academic papers, texts or studies than in poetry or novels;  according to [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=let%27s%20think%2Clet%20us%20think&year_start=1650&year_end=2006&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clet%20%27s%20think%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clet%20us%20think%3B%2Cc0), its equivalent *let us think* has been overtaken by the contracted *let's think* in recent years.

Google Ngram 1570-1750
[image]
Google Ngram 1750-1990
[image]

### When (and why) is “let us” contracted as “let's”?

The following might shed some light...

> First-person inclusive *let*-imperatives (let us/let's) are commonly
>   considered as proposals for **joint action by speaker and addressee**, but
>   there are some cases which diverge from the cohortative usage. Thus,
>   *let's* can also be speaker-oriented and function e.g. as a
>   (self-)exhortative announcement. Or it can be addressee-oriented,
>   carrying a “second person quasi-imperative meaning”
>   <sub>(Biber et al. 1999:1117; cf. De Clerck 2004:218f)</sub>

Sources: [Peter Viney's Blog](https://peterviney.wordpress.com/about/elt-articles/apostrophes/); Wikipedia [Apostrophe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Historical_development); Christina Cavella and Robin A. Kernodle [The Story of the Apostrophe](http://www.american.edu/cas/tesol/pdf/upload/WP-2004-CavellaKernodle-Past-Affects.pdf); Wikipedia [Cohortative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hortative#Cohortative); Edited by Andreas H. Jucker [Early Modern English News Discourse](https://books.google.it/books?id=rZI5AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA122&lpg=PA122&dq=cohortative%20let%27s%20%22let%20us%22&source=bl&ots=yE0J2gQCnn&sig=FLGQhy4w7eJrAKONEZ6gM0fTvkM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0jIqVa3xOoveUYefg9AN&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%20let's%20%22let%20us%22&f=false)

Answer (score 4):

The earliest usage, I found out, could be credited to Shakespeare.

- Let's hold more chat— Shakespeare, **1588**;
- Let us begone from this place— Dickens, 1840.

> Innovatory colloquial variants, irregular in form, have been brought
>   into the language in America (and thence elsewhere) in the 20c:

- Let's you and I take 'em on for a set— W.Faulkner, 1929;
- Let's you and me duck out of here— D. Macdonald, 1950

(From Fowler's Modern English Usage)

Comment: *Let's you and me* could be taken to treat *you and me* as being appositive to *us*.

Comment: *OED* says 1598 for Shakespeare's usage in [*Love's Labour's Lost*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=oB4WAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=%22+If+you+denie+to+daunce,+lets+holde+more+chat%22&source=bl&ots=KlVheu665r&sig=HkaUud2pUC8WWxnHZF-1QaZuJnQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nCMfVZa_LcqyyAS8iYDwCQ&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22%20If%20you%20denie%20to%20daunce%2C%20lets%20holde%20more%20chat%22&f=false) and the original book I found is from 1598. Also, the original usage doesn't have apostrophe: *If you denie to daunce, lets holde more chat.*

Answer (score 2):

In Dutch and German, a similar construct with "laten we" / "lassen wir" (literally "let we") is possible. See for example http://taaladvies.net/taal/advies/vraag/483/laat_ons_laten_we/. This makes it plausible that the origins of using "let" for suggestions go back to before the West Germanic languages split.

Comment: The question is not about the etymology of using "let" as a suggestion, but about the _contraction_ of "let us" to "let's", which does not exist in Dutch. (The question's title is a bit misleading, though.)

Comment: @tjalling The contraction of "let us" to "let's" is used in [cohortative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hortative#Cohortative) sentences. This includes making suggestions: Let's meet up for a coffee.

Comment: @Mari-Lou I'm not disputing that. Thanks for introducing me to the term _cohortative_ by the way. What I meant to state was that it's cohortative use (although I didn't know the term) was a given in the question, and _given that (co)hortative use_, the question asks why **let's** is the only instance where contraction occurs. Did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: @tjalling No, you didn't misunderstand my question. It seems that *let's* in its contracted form, is quite unique. I am still searching for a reason why an imperative  phrase such as: *"Give us your money!"* was never contracted to *Give's  the money!* Where the pronoun  "us" could colloquially stand for "me" or the first-person plural "us".

Answer (score 2):

The interesting thing here is that it is probably first a degeneration of an answer rather than the imperative statement.  It could be a mark of that oh-so-typical human impatience that contracted this short phrase.

> "Shall we come up with an example?"
>   Let us!

The origination of the contraction is dated around the time of Elizabethan England (1567, according to M-W).  It is certainly likely that, even if Shakespeare did use it in his plays (Henry VI P2, "let's kill all the lawyers"), it was well in use colloquially first.

Another point to make is that English lacks a simple conjugation of the first-person plural imperative, while both Germanic and Romantic languages have consistent presentations.  The contraction may have been a partial result of this lack, in that there is clearly a need for a simple way for language to express this type of imperative.

Answer (score 2):

In Glaswegian dialect "give us" is often contracted in this way. The verb itself is changed to "gie" (interestingly, it becomes regular: past simple and past participle "gied") and "give us" is commonly abbreviated to "gies" (pronounced "gheez" and in exactly the same way as the third person singular)

Comment: A reference would be appreciated, if that's possible, or writing a sample sentence using this *gies*

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwMfHvl-2ck

this is an example from a scottish TV comedy from the 1990's

Comment: http://www.scotlandnow.dailyrecord.co.uk/lifestyle/video-25-glaswegian-words-phrases-3895457

Comment: OK, if you wouldn't mind including the citation: "*Gie us a swatch of yer paper.*" along with the link in your actual answer, that would be great. Comments have a tendency if getting arbitrarily deleted, instead posts are more "protected". Thanks :)

Comment: +1 from me anyways, I got to catch up with my beauty sleep, so I can't hang around waiting :)

Comment: ahh parli Glasgow? i spent a while hunting for something more concrete on  scots vocab and orthography before deleting the original. i'll get back to you