# "We must away ere break of day": What is this grammar? Is it alive?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

This phrase appears in a [song of the dwarves](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Far_Over_the_Misty_Mountains_Cold) in Tolkien's *The Hobbit*:

> Far over the Misty Mountains cold
> To dungeons deep and caverns old
> **We must away ere break of day**
> To find our long forgotten gold.

Tolkien was an outstanding linguist, and I guess this line is one of the antique structures he often used in such poems. To my knowledge, the line means “We must go away before dawn”, but omits the main verb completely. What is this structure exactly? Does it appear in contemporary English in any way?

Comment: Have you looked up any problematic words in a dictionary? What did it say, and in what way were you left puzzled?

Comment: Poetry and songs often use language that would sound unusual in normal speech. "Ere" is the only word in the highlighted line that is archaic in contemporary English, but the syntax of that line would be somewhat stilted in normal conversation. Likewise, "Mountains cold" and "caverns old" is non-standard usage, but acceptable in a song or poem.

Comment: The missing verb in the line is also unusual in contemporary English. In Early Modern English, *must go* was often abbreviated to just *must*. (And *must* in sentences with no verb usually meant *must go*.) For example, Hamlet says *I must to England*. So it means *we must go away ere break of day*, or more idiomatically *we have to depart before dawn.*

Comment: @PeterShor Excellent point! I guess in that line, _away_ is actually acting as a verb, which is nonstandard usage. The only line that really works in modern, spoken English is the last one. Modern usage, at least in 1965, would be _[we gotta get out of this place.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_Gotta_Get_out_of_This_Place)_ ;-)

Comment: ere=before, I don't think anyone mentioned that.

Comment: Thank you all! You all gave really great explanations. In fact I already know what this line means :) What I am interested about is the structure itself: I have never seen one like this, lefting out the main verb, from a sentence.

Comment: Can you make that clear in the question?

Comment: @MετάEd Of course. Happened.

Comment: My [answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/238532/44619) on an unrelated question, shows that omitting the main verb was common with *away*. And here is an [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=let+us+away%2Clet%27s+away&year_start=1750&year_end=1950&corpus=18&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clet%20us%20away%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clet%20%27s%20away%3B%2Cc0) showing how frequent ‘*lets away*’ was.

Comment: Shakespeare, "must away", also  here: http://www.shakespeareswords.com/Search.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this example, *away* means *go away*. The verb *go* is suppressed. It is an archaism, the sort of thing that Tolkien was fond of. It is rare in modern texts, but has been around for hundreds of years.

Here are some examples from the New English Dictionary:

> **1375** Otherwais mych thai noch avay.
>   **1393** Whither awaie with my hens, foxe?
>   **1594** I will away to Barnet presently.
>   **1623** We must away euery man to his lodging.
>   **1872** Meantime we must away.

Comment: 'Away with you !' and 'Out !' are comparable and still in use,

Comment: @Hugh Agreed. The OP's construction contains a suppressed infinitive "go". The construction you are comparing contains a suppressed imperative "go". These are very similar, and sometimes hard to sort, such as Superman's "Up, up, and away!"

Comment: To quote another dictionary, the OED has for **away** (adverb) "III. In elliptical uses, with main verb implied. ...  10.   a. Used after auxiliary verbs, as *may, shall, will*, etc. To go away, get away, depart. Now chiefly with *must*. *archaic*."