# Subject in sentence with only object pronoun

Tags: pronouns, subjects, personal-pronouns

> Let us go

is a correct construction in the English language and definitely not:

> Let we go

However, the question is: since *us* is an object-case pronoun, what is the subject of this sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an imperative, and in English the imperative tense only is possible in the second person.

So grammatically, the subject has to be *"you"*.

It can't be interpreted literally; it's an idiom whose meaning isn't really an imperative that you do something, but a suggestion that we do something.

Comment: But the Cambridge dictionary calls it the the "first person plural imperative."

Comment: Also the verb is sometimes called a quasi-modal.  Here are extensive answers about "let us" and "let's" https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/237378/etymology-of-let-us-and-lets