# What kind of grammar explains the common string "Let us"?

Tags: grammar, phrases, sentence, clauses, predicate

What kind of the grammar is shown by the group of two words "let us"?
Is it a phrase or a predicate or a clause ... or something else?

Comment: It's an idiom. Originally it was an imperative, but now it's just an invitation, and it's always contracted as _let's_. Using the full form is unusual and draws attention to the construction, raising the formality. As to what part of speech it is, it's a verb that must be followed by an infinitive without _to_; the subject of the infinitive is first person plural inclusive, i.e, the speaker and the addressees (and maybe others).

Comment: @JohnLawler Well! Could we also use "let we" instead of "let us"? I feel that "let we" is incorrect.

Comment: Too bad. _Let us_ is correct, and *_Let we_ is incorrect. Don't trust your feelings about what's "incorrect".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Yes, I apparently did. Apologies, and thanks. The _us_ is the object of _let_ and the subject of the infinitive following, so it's the right word in the right place, since direct objects and infinitive subjects are both sposta be objective (_us_) and not nominative (_we_).

Comment: Note that "Let us pray" is a very well established idiom in religious contexts.  (And "Let us prey" is very well established as a pun.)

Comment: "Let us" is not a constituent, but part of a larger one. The non-contracted "us" suggests that it's more than likely the ordinary "let" (as opposed to the imperative "let"), where the meaning is "allow", as in "They let us have our ball back", where "us" is object of the catenative verb "let". Alternatively, but less likely, it's part of a 1st person inclusive _let_-imperative construction where "let" is again a catenative verb with an NP object and a bare infinitival clause as second complement, as in "Let us get our ball back".

Comment: Also informative is https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/237378/etymology-of-let-us-and-lets.

Comment: "let us" in itself is a sentence fragment, i.e. a group of words that don't form a sentence or clause. You need to add a verb e.g. "let us go" to get a grammatical sentence.

Answer (score -1):

"Let" is a causative verb and it is used by the person who wants to ask politely for something. For example: Let us go, Let her go, Let him go, and let them go.

As you can see here, after "Let" the form of the object is in the objective case and the verb is all infinitive.

Let's is the short form of "Let us" and used when a person wants to ask for something to somebody, especially when the listener is recommend to do something together with the asker.

For example: Let's go home. Let's get out for a smoke, etc.

get sb to do something, have sb do something, help sb (to) do something, make sb do something, and let sb do something are causative.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not a good answer. You need to bring out the contrast between 1st person inclusive _let_-imperative clauses and non-imperative clauses with ordinary "let" (meaning "allow").